# Plot all categories in boxplot or violinplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot, violin-plot

I have a matplotlib figure with a few violinplots on it (although this question would apply to any similar plot or other dataframe situation, not just violinplots).  I currently run my code and it spits out the figure, with one violinplot per category.  The code looks something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random_integers(low=0,high=1000,size=(100,1)),
                  columns=['row0']
                  )

df['r0_range']='temp' #create a new column 'r0_range', give it a preliminary value
#make assignments depending on value of row0
df['r0_range'][df['row0']<=250]='[0,250]'
df['r0_range'][df['row0']>250]='(250,500]'
df['r0_range'][df['row0']>500]='(500,750]'
df['r0_range'][df['row0']>750]='(750,1000]'

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax1 = sns.violinplot(data=df, x='r0_range', y='row0', inner=None, ax=ax1)
```

Which pops out the following:

[image: violin plots with four violins]

I want to include on my figure a fifth violinplot that represents *all* of the data in all of the categories.  Is there an elegant way to do that without having to copy the row0 data into new rows of the dataframe?

Comment: Not an answer, but you may want to note that `pd.cut(df['row0'], [0, 250, 500, 1000])` simplifies your binning a great deal.

Comment: ... with a `750` in there as well of course.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will do what you are looking for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 1001, 100), columns=['row0'])
g = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['row0'], [0, 250, 500, 750, 1000]))
for name, data in g.groups.items():
    df[name] = df.loc[data]['row0']
sns.violinplot(data=df, inner=None, ax=ax1)
```

[image]